# How to use Nginx as a secure reverse proxy for a websocket running on a NanoCurrency node

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, websocket

I have a server running `Ubuntu 20.04`, set up with an SSH Key, and I have installed Nano using Docker -

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped -d -p 7075:7075/udp -p 7075:7075 -p 127.0.0.1:7076:7076 -p 127.0.0.1:7078:7078 -v /root/nano/:/root --name nano nanocurrency/nano:latest
```

On the VPS GUI ports 22, 443, and 7075 are open for inbound traffic.

I have a working `WebSocket` running on `localhost:7078` which returns a stream of data to the terminal.

`Nginx version 1.18.0` is installed and when I run `systemctl status nginx` it claims to be active with no errors, but when I try to connect from my laptop nothing happens.

Here's my Nginx config -

```
server {
    listen 443;

    # host name to respond to
    server_name 000.000.00.000;

    location / {
        # switch off logging
        access_log off;

        # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:7080
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

And node.js Websocket -

```
const WS = require('ws');
const ReconnectingWebSocket = require('reconnecting-websocket');

// Create a reconnecting WebSocket.
// In this example, we wait a maximum of 2 seconds before retrying.
const ws = new ReconnectingWebSocket('ws://localhost:7078', [], {
        WebSocket: WS,
        connectionTimeout: 1000,        
        maxRetries: 100000,
        maxReconnectionDelay: 2000
});

// As soon as we connect, subscribe to block confirmations
ws.onopen = () => {
        const subscription = {
                "action": "subscribe", 
                "topic": "confirmation"
        }
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(subscription));
};

// The node sent us a confirmation
ws.onmessage = msg => {
        console.log(msg.data);
        if (msg.data.topic === "confirmation") {
                console.log ('Confirmed', data.message.hash)
        }
};
```